# How to use a jQuery variable returned from a PHP function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I think I am close but I am stuck at the moment. Here is a little background.

I'm using Wordpress, and I have a plugin for a gallery.  Each gallery has an ID and I'm trying to accomplish when a user clicks on the gallery link, the gallery will change to the corresponding gallery.  The gallery is being displayed like so:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[slideshow gallery_id="1"]'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (function_exists('slideshow')) { slideshow(true, "1", false, array()); } ?>
```

both do the same thing -

where `gallery_id` specifies the correct gallery.  I'm using AJAX to run some code to get back the correct gallery ID when the user clicks the link.

```
jQuery('.gallery-btn').click(function() {
    var galleryId = jQuery(this).data('gallery');

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/themes/thetheme/gallery.php",
        data: {action: galleryId},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            console.log(output);
        }
    })

})
```

PHP code in gallery.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $galleryId = $_POST['action'];
    passId($galleryId);
}

function passId($id) {
    echo $id;
}

?>
```

`output` returns the ID that I need to then pass into the PHP code `[slideshow gallery_id="$theID"]`.

How can I use `output` from the success function in my PHP code?

Comment: What php code do you want to use the javascript variable 'output' in?

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode('[slideshow gallery_id="$ID"]'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. At least not in the manner that you are proposing.  The PHP code that generates your gallery is executed before the page is initially loaded.  You can't have jQuery call a script after the page loads and pass it to an already executed PHP function.

That being said, you may have some other options to update the gallery after the page loads. Not being familiar with what gallery you are using, I can't give specific advice. However, I can talk about general approach.

You might be able to use javascript/jQuery to change the original HTML output by the gallery (i.e. `<img>` tags, `src` links, etc.).  In this case you might use AJAX to pull down gallery metadata as needed to make  these changes.

I simpler approach might be to simply output an entire new block of gallery HTML (perhaps using the initial function) and just replace this for the current HTML within the DOM.  In this case you could have the AJAX call a server-side script that re-runs the gallery function and returns the HTML content for insertion into the DOM by javascript.

Comment: I've tried running the function 'do_shortcode' in the PHP side and then return the HTML output, but I get console errors saying "Call to undefined function do_shortcode()"

Comment: @Romes You need to make sure you have that function and all its dependencies included from where you are calling it.

Comment: Great, I think that solved my problem. Ill update how I did it when I can.  I had to load wp again for it to work.